# Please can somebody help to explain this code

Tags: binary, python-2.6

This is the code I was given;

```
d = 0

binary = raw_input('Please enter a number between 0 - 11111111 in binary: ')

for digit in binary:
     d = d*2 + int(digit)   
     print d
```

It's this part below which I really don't understand:

```
     for digit in binary:
          d = d*2 + int(digit)
```

Any help is appretiated, thankyou

Comment: The function is converting from binary to denary ("normal") numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you wanted to understand what the sequence of digits "6", "9", "2" means. You can follow this logic:

1. Start with 0
2. Multiply the number you are on by 10 and add the digit you are on.
3. Go to the next digit.
4. If there are no more digits, stop. The number you are on is the number the digit sequence encodes.
5. Go to step 2.

So, let's try it for "6", "9", "2".

We start with 0.

10*0 + 6 -> 6
10*6 + 9 -> 69
10*69 + 2 -> 692
No next digit, so we stop.

So from "6", "9", "2", we get the number 692, which is correct.

The code uses a 2 because it's processing a number in base 2 rather than base 10. This is how numbering systems work.